# Why speed is slow when writing data in from html table to excel sheet using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba

The VBA code is working fine but taking long time to write data, is there any other way to get data from html table/url.

```
Sub pull_option_data()
        Dim tod As String, UnderLay As String, exp As String
        Dim IE As Object
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Dim Tbl As HTMLTable, Cel As HTMLTableCell, Rw As HTMLTableRow, Col As HTMLTableCol
    Dim TrgRw As Long, TrgCol As Long

'START INTERNET EXPLORER AND NAVIGATE TO URL
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    Dim ColOff As Long
    For Nurl = 2 To 151
    UnderLay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("A" & Nurl).Value
    ColOff = (Nurl - 2) * 23
TrgRw = 1

    IE.navigate "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=" & UnderLay & ""

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

'GET DATA FROM TABLE AND PUT TO SHEET
    Set doc = IE.document
    Set Tbl = doc.getElementById("octable")
    TrgRw = TrgRw
    For Each Rw In Tbl.Rows
        TrgCol = 1
        For Each Cel In Rw.Cells
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + TrgCol).Value = Cel.innerText
            TrgCol = TrgCol + Cel.colSpan
        Next Cel
        TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
    Next Rw

TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
Next Nurl

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a loop in a loop - that's going to be slow.

Comment: Depending on how large the table is will depend on the speed this this type of sub. Bare in mind that your code is going through ever single cell of the html table. Depending on how the table is populated on the web page, you could look into WinHTTPRequests and possibly retrieve it through that.

Answer (score 0):

think on more programmatic solution of the task:

- add application.screenupdating = False at the top of the procedure
- get all values in .Sheets("URLList") as array.
- create new 2D array. Write keys from the worksheet into the 1st column and find HTML table results (as you do it) and save the in the 2nd column.
- in the end simply paste the whole array instead of looping through the worksheet